# Single SciPy CSR Matrix from Large Dask Array

Tags: python, dask, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse dask array with 200k rows and 150k columns. I want to convert this sparse dask array into a **single** scipy sparse CSR matrix for use with collaborative filtering models from the [implicit](https://github.com/benfred/implicit) library. How can I do this?

Current attempt/ideas:

(1) Simply using compute.

```py
import dask.array as da
import sparse
nusers = 200_000
intens = 150_000
rng = da.random.default_rng()
x = rng.random((nusers, nitems))
x[x < 0.95] = 0
s = s.map_blocks(sparse.COO)
# this kills program due to out of memory
s_csr = s.compute().tocsr()
```

(2) Incrementally creating the sparse array, converting it to
a scipy csr format, writing that to disk, and then resuming
computation. Note, the `sys.getsizeof(sp_matrix)` when `sp_matrix`
is the result of `sparse.concatenate()` will also increasingly
require more RAM; however, casting this matrix to a scipy csr matrix,
results in an object requiring only 48 bytes of memory. Note, I have only partially tested this strategy, which is how I experimentally
determined these byte sizes. This strategy is **extremely** slow and would likely require manual garbage collection (`import gc; gc.collect()`) as well.

```py
def get_next_chunk(s: DaskArray):
  """Gets next chunk of DaskArray""" 
  raise NotImplementedError

# rechunk the data such that concatenation
# along the first axis will incrementally
# create the entire matrix
s = s.rechunk((some_value, nitems))

# get the first chunk
# this will have shape (some_value, nitems)
sp_matrix = get_next_chunk(s)

# for all remaining chunks, 
# concatenate said chunks to the sp
# matrix, then cast that to csr
while (chunk = get_next_chunk(s)):
  sp_matrix = sparse.concatenate((sp_matrix, chunk))
  # note: could intermittently write the 
  # sparse matrix to disk in case of failure
  if (sys.getsizeof(sp_matrix)/2**30) > threshold_GB:
    # or maybe sp_matrix_tmp = sp_matrix.toscr()
    # del sp_matrix; sp_matrix = sp_matrix_tmp
    sp_matrix = sp_matrix.tocsr() 
    save_npz(fpath, sp_matrix)
    sp_matrix = sparse.COO.from_scipy_sparse(sp_matrix)

sp_matrix = sp_matrix.tocsr()
save_npz(final, sp_matrix)
```

My hardware: Lubuntu 22.04 LTS laptop with 8 GB RAM and 8 GB swap space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with the first approach. However, the resulting scipy.sparse CSR matrix will be ~18GB of memory, which is why you are running out of memory.

I ran this code (same as yours, but 10x smaller).

```py
import dask.array as da
import sparse
nusers = 20_000
nitems = 150_000
rng = da.random.default_rng()
x = rng.random((nusers, nitems))
x[x < 0.95] = 0
s = x.map_blocks(sparse.COO.from_numpy)
z = s.compute().tocsr()

print(z.indptr.nbytes + z.indices.nbytes + z.data.nbytes)
```

The result is `1_799_960_676`. 10x larger would give ~18GB.

So if you *must* have it as a single CSR, find a computer with more memory.

Comment: Over the past couple days, I have also come to this conclusion, unfortunately. I've been trying my best to work around this memory limit, but it looks like it's virtually impossible. Fortunately, I have recently discovered that `dask` supports matrix factorization algorithms like SVD, so i'll probably just have to homeroll a recommendation algorithm using that.